# Angular Material Date filter on single Adapter

Tags: angular, angular-material2, date-formatting

I have created a custom date for my `mat-datepicker` by doing the following:

```
export const PICK_FORMATS = {
  parse: {dateInput: {month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'}},
  display: {
      dateInput: 'input',
      monthYearLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'short'},
      dateA11yLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'},
      monthYearA11yLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long'}
  }
};

class PickDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
      if (displayFormat === 'input') {
          return formatDate(date,'dd-MMM-yyyy',this.locale);;
      } else {
          return date.toDateString();
      }
  }
}

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: PickDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: PICK_FORMATS }
  ]
})
```

The issue I am having is that I have multiple datepickers in my view, but I only want to apply this filter to a single one of them, and that is where I am stuck.  I think I have to provide the single element to the provider, but I am not sure if that is indeed the case, or if it is, I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The MatDatePicker injects the DateAdapter & MAT_DATE_FORMATS to use in the component. So, it will use those provided in your component. If you only want to have them used in only one component: The only solution I see is wrapping it inside a directive which provide these custom implementations.